# Trouble with Intel MKL libraries: segfault / unresolved external symbol

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I am compiling some code trying to use the Intel MKL library eigensolvers. I am already using the VSL RNG's and the DFT libraries without issue. I am compiling and running everything in Visual Studio with Intel Parallel Studio XE installed. I have ensured that the `mkl` flag is enabled in project properties.

```
include 'lapack.f90'
program heev_test
    use lapack95
    implicit none
    integer , parameter :: dp = kind(0.0d0)
    complex(dp) :: matrix(4,4)
    real(dp) :: eigs(4)
    matrix = (1.0_dp,0.0_dp)
    call zheev(matrix, eigs)
    print*, eigs
    read(*,*)
    stop  
end program
```

Running this code yields a segfault on two machines I have tested it on so far. I believe the issue is that the F77 routines are being called which require more arguments (documentation [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-fortran-heevr#6ADF761A-127A-4C9B-9A2A-1A8AA4602CE1)). I would like to use the far simpler F95 routines. According to the documentation, I should replace `zheev` with `heev`. So I tried that, but then I get the error

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ZHEEV_F95 referenced in function _MAIN__
```

`ZHEEV_F95` has an interface defined in the `lapack.f90` file.

The only other thing I have right now is that the documentation says I should also include `mkl.fi`, but doing so I get the following compilation errors

```
Error       error #6218: This statement is positioned incorrectly and/or has syntax errors.     C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\\mkl\include\lapack.f90    21  
Error       error #6790: This is an invalid statement; an END [PROGRAM]  statement is required.     C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\\mkl\include\lapack.f90    24  
Error       error #6785: This name does not match the unit name.   [F95_PRECISION]      C:\Program Files (x86)\IntelSWTools\compilers_and_libraries_2018\windows\\mkl\include\lapack.f90    24  
Error       Compilation Aborted (code 1)        
Warning     warning #5427: Program may contain only one main entry routine
```

referring to these lines from the `lapack.f90` file:

```
21  MODULE F95_PRECISION
22      INTEGER, PARAMETER :: SP = KIND(1.0E0)
23      INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DP = KIND(1.0D0)
24  END MODULE F95_PRECISION
```

Comment: Have you specified any additional libraries for linking, or are you just using `/mkl`?

Comment: @francescalus, I've simply enabled the "Use MKL Libraries" option in Project Properties, which is all that is required when I use the VSL and DFT routines.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to link the Lapack95 library explicitly, which is not linked with simply the -mkl flag. For example, on Windows 64-bit with 4 byte integers compiled with the Intel Fortran compiler, use

```
ifort /Qmkl heev_test.f90 mkl_lapack95_lp64.lib
```

As for the seg fault, I was improperly calling the F77 routines. Since I did not provide an interface for these routines, the compiler did not complain, and when I did call them, it caused a segmentation fault since the arguments were not properly input.

Here is a code which properly calls both routines, and can be verified to produce the same results.

```
include 'lapack.f90'
program heev_test
    use lapack95
    implicit none
    integer , parameter :: dp = kind(0.0d0)
    complex(dp) :: matrix(4,4)
    real(dp) :: eigs(4)
    matrix = (1.0_dp,0.0_dp)
    print*, "checking eigenvalues using zheevr"
    call eigenvalues(matrix,eigs)
    print*, eigs
    matrix = (1.0_dp,0.0_dp)
    print*, "checking eigenvalues using heevr"
    call heevr(matrix,eigs)
    print*, eigs
    read(*,*)
    stop  

contains

    subroutine eigenvalues(a,w)
        complex(dp) :: a(:,:)
        real(dp)    :: w(:)
        character*1 :: jobz, range, uplo
        integer     :: n, m, lda, il, iu, ldz
        real(dp)    :: vl, vu, abstol
        integer     :: info
        integer     :: lwork, liwork, lrwork
        complex(dp) , allocatable :: z(:,:)
        complex(dp) , allocatable :: work(:)
        real(dp)    , allocatable :: rwork(:)
        integer     , allocatable :: iwork(:)
        integer     , allocatable :: isuppz(:)

        jobz  = 'N'
        range = 'A'
        uplo  = 'U'
        n = size(a,dim=1)
        lda = max(1,n)
        vl = -huge(vl)
        vu = +huge(vl)
        il = 1
        iu = n
        abstol = 0.0_dp
        ldz = max(1,n)
        lwork = max(1,2*n)
        lrwork = max(1,24*n)
        liwork = max(1,10*n)
        allocate(work(lwork))
        allocate(rwork(lrwork))
        allocate(iwork(liwork))
        allocate(z(ldz,max(1,n)))
        allocate(isuppz(2*max(1,n)))
        lwork = -1
        liwork = -1
        lrwork = -1     

        call zheevr(jobz, range, uplo, n, a, lda, vl, vu, il, iu, abstol, m, w, &
            &       z, ldz, isuppz, work, lwork, rwork, lrwork, iwork, liwork, info) 

        lwork = work(1)
        liwork = iwork(1)
        lrwork = rwork(1)
        deallocate(work,iwork,rwork)        
        allocate(work(lwork))
        allocate(iwork(liwork))
        allocate(rwork(lrwork))

        call zheevr(jobz, range, uplo, n, a, lda, vl, vu, il, iu, abstol, m, w, &
            &       z, ldz, isuppz, work, lwork, rwork, lrwork, iwork, liwork, info)  

        deallocate(work,iwork,rwork)

        if (info /= 0) then
            print*, "diagonalization failed, info = ", info
            read(*,*)
            stop
        end if

    end subroutine
end program
```

In my case, the f95 libraries were not installed on the target machine (a remote cluster), so I had to fall back on the f77 library, for which the above subroutine is essentially equivalent to the f95 interface for a square matrix and can be easily modified. See the documentation for definitions of variables.

Note that according to the documentation, heevr/zheevr is a more efficient routine than heev/zheev, so I switched them.